# Deploy a microsoft bot onto a local machine and host it

Tags: node.js, deployment, botframework, chatbot

I have built a bot using microsoft botframework and nodejs. Now, I want to deploy it to a local machine and later host it and get the https url. I understood that it should be running on IIS but i don't understand where to start first. Can anyone help me to deploy it onto a local machine and how to host it?

Answer (score 2):

[Here's a good place to start!](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-3.0)

You need to do the following

1. Install Restify

   ```
   npm install --save restify
   ```
2. Set up your app to use Restify, here's a sample code:

   ```
   var restify = require('restify');
   var builder = require('botbuilder');

   // Setup Restify Server
   var server = restify.createServer();
   server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function () {
       console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url); 
   });

   // Create chat connector for communicating with the Bot Framework Service
   var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
       appId: process.env.MicrosoftAppId,
       appPassword: process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword
   });

   // Listen for messages from users 
   server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());

   // Receive messages from the user and respond by echoing each message back (prefixed with 'You said:')
   var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, function (session) {
       session.send("You said: %s", session.message.text);
   });
   ```
3. Run your bot with

   ```
   node app.js
   ```
4. Download an open the BotFramework Emulator and set it to point to uri in which your bot is hosted, i.e.:
       http://localhost:3980/api/messages

Comment: I would add that if you literally want to host the bot on your local machine (and not just test locally) then you can setup IIS, or equivalent, to produce a custom endpoint.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I want to host locally. Since it is a node js application, how to host it on windows?
After hosting how create the custom endpoint?