# BotFramework - Bot Composer - Deploy to local

Tags: botframework, chatbot, bot-framework-composer

How can we deploy Bot designed in Microsoft Bot composer (of Bot framework) to local machine instead of Azure.

As of now there is only one dropdown entry in Publishing target, while creating publishing profile - "Publish Bot to Azure"

Answer (score 0):

Bot Composer, unfortunately, only natively supports publishing to the cloud. To publish a bot to a machine requires more steps. I found this answer useful: [Deploy a microsoft bot onto a local machine and host it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52314414/deploy-a-microsoft-bot-onto-a-local-machine-and-host-it)